# Values were not specified for some of the required parameters (UPDATE Clause)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Another ghost mistake that I cant see what is the cause... this time with my update clause:

```
Protected Friend Sub modificarC(ByVal cad As String, ByVal empres As String, ByVal direcc As String, ByVal tel As String, ByVal corr As String, ByVal comen As String)
    Dim com As String = "Update Cliente SET Empresa=@Empresa,Direccion=@Direccion,Telefono=@telfono,Correo=@Correo,Comentario=@Comentario WHERE Id_Cliente=@Id_Cliente"
    Try
        con.Open()
        comando = New OleDbCommand(com, con)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Empresa", empres)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", direcc)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefono", tel)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", corr)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comentario", comen)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_Cliente", cad)
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
        comando.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Problemas en la consulta: " + ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And the strangest thing is that I lead me to another query of the same type that it works...

[image: Error message]

*"Values were not specified for some of the required parameters"*

The parameters are declared in the same order as the table and add them in the same order as the query , because im using Access.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Check make sure the table definitions fields match the update query ones. Also, you may try placing the @Id_Cliente as the first parameter.

Comment: If any of those variables are blank, null. empty but the db requires them it could fail.  Use the slightly longer form `Add(p, type).Value = var` instead of AddWithValue

Comment: my table and my fields match correctly with my query... Also, I tried your suggestion, but got the same error :/

Comment: Plutonix, tried your suggestion too, and still fails... (Also, all my vars store the data...)

Comment: Does OleDb and MS Access support named parameters?

Comment: yes, Access support that.. Also, finaly found whats the problem yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

Update the spelling for the Telefono parameter in your query to `@Telefono`. You have it set to `@telfono`.